How do I validate that a field has the same value as another?
I am trying to implement a validation that checks if the email field is the same value as the reemail field. I previously used Yup and you could do this with the oneOf method but I am not sure how one would do the same with Zod.
I tried using superRefine but it doesn't seem to work. This is my schema:
export const validationSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().email({ message: "Enter a valid email." }).min(1, "This field is required."),
    reemail: z.string().min(1, "This field is required."),
}).superRefine((data, ctx) => {
    if (data.email !== data.reemail) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: "The emails do not match.",
            path: ["reemail"]
        });
    }
 });


Use refine as below:
export const validationSchema = z
  .object({
    email: z
      .string()
      .email({ message: "Enter a valid email." })
      .min(1, "This field is required."),
    reemail: z.string().min(1, "This field is required."),
  })
  .refine(
    (values) => {
      return values.email === values.reemail;
    },
    {
      message: "The emails do not match.",
      path: ["reemail"],
    }
  );

